# dask merge/to csv results in crash

Tags: dask

I previously used pandas to merge dataframes but have come across memory issues.

I have a huge dataframe that I have merged from several other big dataframes using dask. All the read_csv and dd.merge with several dataframes are fast, but until the last step where to_csv results in crash (I presume it's memory issue).

I merged df1 with four other dataframes individually like this:

```
df1 = dd.merge(df1,df2, on='ID', how='inner')
df1 = dd.merge(df1,df3, on='ID', how='inner')
df1 = dd.merge(df1,df4, on='ID', how='inner')
df1 = dd.merge(df1,df5, on='ID', how='inner')
```

I tried chunksize like this but it doesn't help:

```
df = df.to_csv('filename.csv', chunksize=1000000)
```

I'm guessing it is the merging issues that cause the memory error which results in crash but I how else could I merge the without causing this problem ?